# change the below to parameterized query With conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, .net, vb.net, asp-classic

How to change the below to parameterized query which has if-conditions...?I want to make it to parameterised query qith command object...

```
strQry="SELECT distinct EnrolID" &_
        " FROM " & strview & " WHERE ProgramID=" &vP&_
        " AND EnrolStatus = 'ZZY' AND CampusID=" &vC


if vW <> "" THEN           
    strQry=strQry + " AND WID like '%" &WID& "%'"   
end if
    if vBID<>0 THEN 
        strQry=strQry + " AND BID=" &vBID           
    end if              
if vProgramID= "2" then 
    if vT<>0 THEN
        strQry=strQry + " AND eid=" &vT         
    end if

    if vYr<>0 THEN  
        strQry=strQry + " AND Year(A_Dt)=" &vY          
    end if       
end if
strQry = strQry + " ORDER BY EN"
set objRS=createObject("ADODB.recordset")
obj.Open strQry, Conn
```

Comment: You can't parameterize table names (or any other identifiers), and adding stuff like `AND`s also requires dynamic SQL (so you're stuck with concatenation for those parts).  You can only parameterize variables (like those used in the conditions).  Why are you dynamically choosing which table/view to get data from?  And `YEAR(A_dt)` will ignore indices (you should be using a range query), besides having a terrible column name.

Comment: upon condition the code is just updating the query. 
How can i make it to parameterised query keeping the if condition checks intact

Comment: @Papai First off are you using [tag:.net] or [tag:asp-classic] I asked this because they are two different technologies which is already confusing those who are attempting to provide you with an answer. Also are you definitely using [tag:mysql] or is it [tag:sql-server] perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, your base query isn't parameterized. I've fixed that below, but **if your strview variable is unsanitized user input** (and not, for example, a constant you declared) **then you are still very vulnerable to SQL injection.** That said:

```
Dim SQLCmd As New MySqlCommand

strQry="SELECT distinct EnrolID" &_
    " FROM " & strview & " WHERE ProgramID = @ProgramID" &_
    " AND EnrolStatus = 'ZZY' AND CampusID = @CampusID"

SQLCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProgramID", vP)
SQLCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CampusID", vC)

If vW <> "" Then           
    strQry = strQry + " AND WID like @WID"
    SQLCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WID", "%" & WID & "%")  
End If
If vBID <> 0 Then 
    strQry = strQry + " AND BID = @BID"
    SQLCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BID", vBID)          
End If              
If vProgramID = "2" Then 
    If vT <> 0 Then
        strQry = strQry & " AND eid = @eID"
        SQLCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eID", vT)        
    End If

    If vYr <> 0 Then  
        strQry = strQry& " AND Year(A_Dt) = @Year"
        SQLCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Year", vY)         
    End If       
End If
strQry = strQry & " ORDER BY EN"
SQLCmd.CommandText = strQry
```

Comment: The original code is [tag:asp-classic] don't think the OP wants a [tag:.net] one even if they have tagged it as such.

Comment: Seriously who upvoted this, do people actually read the question before upvoting answers?